# C# parse DateTime year to int

Tags: c#

How can I parse DateTime variables only year to Integer type?

I would like to parse DateTime variable (2008-06-08) to a integer type variable that would contain only year (2008)

I have tried converting DateTime to string and string parsing to int, but maybe there is a better way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have a `DateTime` as stated you just need to use the [`Year` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-us/library/system.datetime.year(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int year = dt.Year;
```

If you have a string you have to parse it first, f.e. by using `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2008-06-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: +1 perfect, OP may also need to consider specific CultureInfo instead of InvariantCulture, but then this is only if needed :) .

Comment: I get this error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @JustinaSeliokaite: when do you get it? You've stated that you have `DateTime` variables. So you actually don't have `DateTime` variables but `string` variables which you want to parse to `DateTime`(as guessed)? Then show what string you have tried to parse. The code above works in any culture as i'm using `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: my date is DateTime? variable.

Comment: @JustinaSeliokaite Does your date string match the Format string? The format of the date in the first parameter must match the format specified in the second. (see msdn article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx ) If it's a datetime? (nullable Datetime), is it null?

Comment: @JustinaSeliokaite you would have to do int = dt.Value.Year; in the case if you had a DateTime? variable